# How to integrate/merge multiple extent reports into one single report using selenium, extent report v3xx

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-report, extent

I am running selenium scripts using jenkins jobs/multijob and its creating multiple html reports for different modules.

How can we combine/merge all html reports to one single  report?

Extent report 2 has a feature to combine html report. How can we do the same with extent report 3?

Ref: http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentMerge.html

Comment: The link is dead, can you fix it?

Comment: Alt links: https://www.extentreports.com/ or https://github.com/extent-framework/klov

Answer (score 1):

For appending reports please check the [link](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#htmlreporter-features). For Appending to HtmlReporter use

```
htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
```

If you want to append to an existing report based on reportName, use:

```
extentxReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
```

Refer link for more information.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your extent report class,

```
ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("Specify the file path here where your extent reports should reside",false);
```

Parameter `False`- Is used to append the reports of previous run testcase along with newly run testcase.

Parameter `True`- Deletes the history of reports of previous run testcases and shows only the reports of newly run testcases.

Comment: Thanks @prasanna venkatesh! But I think its for extent report version 2x and not v3xx

Comment: HI @HIMANSHUMARKAM checked on Extent report version 3xxx.. Please try this below command..   " htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true); "  For more information verify appending reports section in the following link..    http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#htmlreporter-features

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement. I achieved it. (Extent Report V3 and above)

BaseTest is being extended by all the test class.

```
Class BaseTest{

        public static ExtentReports extent =new ExtentReports();//initiating here is very important
        public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;

@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuiteSetup() {
        String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(filepath+"/Report.html");     
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterSuite() {
        extent.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you BRO. am looking for it for 2 days. It works quite fine in this way. actually i dont understand why someone gave -1